# WiFi issue with RTL8821CE in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (kernel 6.2.0)

Tags: wireless, 22.04

I'm facing the classic issue about very low signal in Ubuntu (while no issue when I had windows).
I've tried following some posts here but with no fix (I'm not an expert). Tried also to install firmware from github but ... no fix.
Secureboot disabled. Tried also to disable bluetooth, with no result.

Here are some command output at this moment:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy


uname -a
Linux ASUS-vivoBook-di-Davide 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


iwconfig 
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          

lspci | fgrep -i wireless
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter


lsmod |fgrep 8821
8821ce               2519040  0
rtw_8821ce             16384  0
rtw_8821c              90112  1 rtw_8821ce
rtw_pci                32768  1 rtw_8821ce
rtw_core              339968  2 rtw_8821c,rtw_pci
cfg80211             1241088  3 rtw_core,mac80211,8821ce


sudo dkms status
rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1: added
rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 6.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
rtw88/0.6, 6.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: I think you have two drivers loaded. Is there any improvement if you do: `sudo modprobe -r 8821ce` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.